# Getter from Store in Vue return ƒ isLoggedIn(state)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have stored in my Vue store the state of the Laravel user, but trying to get it like this:

```js
let isLoggedIn = store.getters.isLoggedIn
```

In the console when calling that variable, I get:

> ƒ isLoggedIn (state) {
> return state.user? true: false;
> }

instead of a `true` or `false`.

My store code:

```js
let store = {
    state: {
        user: '',
    },
    mutations: {
        setAuthUser(state, user) {
            state.user = user;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn(state) {
            return state.user ? true : false
        }
    }
};

export default store;
```

My `app.js`, where I invoke the getter:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let isLoggedIn = store.getters.isLoggedIn
  console.log(isLoggedIn)
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      next({
        path: '/ingresar',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})
```

Comment: Just call the function? `let isLoggedIn = store.getters.isLoggedIn()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270741/undefined-when-calling-state-in-getter-vuex

Comment: The getter is not meant to be invoked as a function. It should work as you've used it, but your store usage is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized the store properly, which is causing the problem you noticed. Your store code is just exporting a plain object instead of a `Vuex.Store`.

To initialize the store:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

let store = /* ... */

export default new Vuex.Store(store)
```

Comment: Hi, i have in app.js: const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: new Vuex.Store(store),
  components: {
      Loading,
    },
    router,
});

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270741/undefined-when-calling-state-in-getter-vuex

Comment: Ok, but `store` in `store.getters.isLoggedIn` refers to the plain object, which is not a `Vuex.Store` instance. You should update the store initialization to export `new Vuex.Store(store)`, and remove the instantiation from `app.js`.